# Can I force my event handler to the bottom of the event handler queue?

Tags: jquery, html

Inside a grid that has a select all column, I would like to respond to each checkbox being checked/unchecked and update the state of the "Select All" header.

My code to update the "Select All" checkbox state is below:

```
//This is just an example to demonstrate the layout. The actual html is verbose and contains a series of spans and inputs

    <div class="a">
       <div class="b" id="c"></div>
       <div class="b"></div>
       <div class="b"></div>
       <div class="b"></div>
       <div class="b"></div>
    </div>

    $(".a").find(".b").not("#c").on("change",checkBoxCheck);

    function checkBoxCheck(){
        //selectAllSetChecked(areAllRowsSelected());
        console.log("areAllRowsSelected() : ")
    }

    function areAllRowsSelected() {
        //NOTE : edtCheckBoxUnchecked seems to be applied after this event fires
        return $(".a").find(".edtCheckBoxUnchecked").length == 0;
    }
```

The code above correctly calls checkBoxCheck, however, I am checking for a class being applied dynamically to an input and that class seems to be applied after "my" change event fires.

```
I am left with this scenario:

[X]
 O --CLICK --> X  areAllRowsSelected() : false
 X
 X
 X

[X]
 X --CLICK-->  O areAllRowsSelected() : true
 X
 X
 X
```

Is there a way that I can make sure my handler is the last handler to be called in an event chain? Perhaps another solution would be to try and determine when a specific class is applied to the checkbox but I don't think that is possible.

**Update:**

The solution I came up with seems kind of hackish, however, my code is not applying the style so this does not require me to jump through hoops.

```
function checkBoxCheck(){
    var allChecked = $(".a").find(".edtCheckBoxUnchecked").length == 1;
    selectAllSetChecked(allChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the specified case you can also do like

```
$(document).on('click','.a>.b',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
if(id=='c')
{
return;
}
checkBoxCheck();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am always looking for a shorthand way of doing things!